# ADO.NET Data Services

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm looking at using ADO.NET Data Services with silverlight.  I've been looking at the 
[Data Model and Data Service Implementations (ADO.NET Data Services/Silverlight)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838239(VS.95).aspx) topic on msdn.  In their example, they build a data model generated from a database, and query entities in the datamodel.  In my case I want to use stored procedures, so I"ve created the data model and added stored procedures instead of tables & views, but now I'm not sure how to execute them.  Does anyone have a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the stored procedures when you build your Entity Framework model.  There's [lots of documentation about this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399203.aspx).  You can also see [a screencast](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/video-245.aspx).

As a point of clarification, I don't think there is anything Data-Services specific about your question.  It's more of an Entity Framework question.

Comment: Strictly speaking, ADO.NET isn't specific to Entity Framework... but in this case, I agree that the questions are about EF, not Astoria